# Mapping custom named parameter from URL to variable in NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

If I have a router like:

```
app.UseMvc(config => {
    config.MapRoute(
        name: "route",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

Is it possible to call methods that have parameter named other than `id` and still bind value from URL.

```
public void SetHeight(int height){
    //height do not binds value from URL to height
}

public void SetWidth(int width){
    //height do not binds value from URL to width
}

public void SetHeight(int id){
    //works as expected however I would like to have different 
    //parameters name for different action on controller
}

public void SetWidth(int id){
    //works as expected however I would like to have different 
    //parameters name for different action on controller
}
```

Is there some annotation or something similar to enable different parameter names?
Something like:

```
public void SetHeight([FromUrl(name = "id")]int height){
     ...
}
```

Comment: Read up on attribute routing

Comment: The normal is to bind them as url parameters (e.g. mysite.com/Controller/SetHeight?height=xxx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
    [Route("[controller]/[action]/{height}")]
    public void SetHeight(int height)
    {
        //height do not binds value from URL to height
    }


    [Route("[controller]/[action]/{width}")]
    public void SetWidth(int width)
    {
        //height do not binds value from URL to width
    }
```